# Matlab: how to rank 2D array and mark the ranking in the other 2D array?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, matlab, sorting, matrix

I am considering an easy algorithm to rank my 2D array and mark their rank in the same size of the 2D array.

For example, I have a matrix in below:

```
[0 2 15 34;
 0 15 21 24;
 0 3 5 8;
 1 14 23 29]
```

The output should be as follow:

```
[1 5 10 16;
 1 10 12 14;
 1 6 7 8;
 4 9 13 15]
```

I am kind of new to matlab, I not sure if the matlab have the functionality to directly do it. Or it would be even better if you could provide some ideas for implementing the algorithm. Thank you very much!

Comment: Do you really want to skip ranks when there are repeated values in the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to replace each element by its rank. I offer three ways to do it; the third seems to be what you want.

Let your example data be defined as

```
data = [0 2 15 34;
        0 15 21 24;
        0 3 5 8;
        1 14 23 29];
```

1. This assigns **equal ranks to equal data values** (as in your example), but **doesn't skip ranks** in that case (your example seems to do so):

   ```
   [~, ~, vv] = unique(data(:));
   result = reshape(vv, size(data));
   ```

   With your example data, this gives

   ```
   result =
        1     3     8    13
        1     8     9    11
        1     4     5     6
        2     7    10    12
   ```
2. This assigns **different ranks to equal data values** (so skipping ranks is out of the question):

   ```
   [~, vv] = sort(data(:));
   [~, vv] = sort(vv);
   result = reshape(vv, size(data));
   ```

   With your example data,

   ```
   result =
        1     5    11    16
        2    10    12    14
        3     6     7     8
        4     9    13    15
   ```
3. This assigns **equal ranks to equal data values**, and in that case it **skips ranks**:

   ```
   [~, vv] = sort(data(:));
   [~, vv] = sort(vv);
   [~, jj, kk] = unique(data(:), 'first');
   result = reshape(vv(jj(kk)), size(data));
   ```

   With your example data,

   ```
   result =
        1     5    10    16
        1    10    12    14
        1     6     7     8
        4     9    13    15
   ```

   Another approach, single-line: for each entry, find how many other entries are smaller, and add 1:

   ```
   result = reshape(sum(bsxfun(@lt,data(:),data(:).'))+1, size(data));
   ```